# Is it possible to bind to the ColumnSpan property?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I am having trouble binding to the ColumnSpan property. After many hours of debugging, I am wondering if it is even possible.

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private int myProperty;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Binding binding = new Binding("MyProperty");
        binding.Source = this;
        btn0.SetBinding(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty, binding);
    }
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return myProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            myProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
        }
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to bind to `Grid.Column` but not `Grid.ColumnSpan`? If it's possible with `ColumnSpan`, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you set a default value for `myProperty` other than zero? Say you set it to 3 and your Grid actually has three or four columns, is the initial value applied correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Thx a lot, Martin, that was it. Compiling fails if property is Zero.
So sick, I lost a day because of this.